# Pegar a última palavra de uma String e colocá-la no início com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho a frase: "**Amanhã vai chover**".
Eu quero pegar a última palavra e deixar assim:
"**chover, Amanhã vai**".

Estou fazendo desse jeito:

```
var frase = 'Amanhã vai chover';
var palavra = strg.split(' ')[0];//
```

Consigo pegar o: **Amanhã**... Agora, como pego o último e deixo no padrão acima, usando JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Três sugestões:

```js
var frase = 'Amanhã vai chover';


// maneira mais moderna A
var palavras = frase.split(' ');
var reordenado1 = `${palavras.pop()}, ${[...palavras].join(' ')}`;
console.log(reordenado1);

// maneira mais moderna B
var palavras = frase.split(' ');
var reordenado2 = [palavras.pop() + ',', ...palavras].join(' ');
console.log(reordenado2);


// maneira mais compatível
var palavras = frase.split(' ');
var reordenado3 = [palavras.pop() + ','].concat(palavras).join(' ');
console.log(reordenado3);
```

Comment: Faltou a vírgula depois de "chover".

Comment: @VictorStafusa :o respondi antes do pequeno almoço... corrigido! Obrigado :)

Comment: Sua resposta me lembra [**isso**](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: @VictorStafusa :)

Answer (score 3):

Existem varias formas, mas leve em consideracao esta que me parece ser simples:

```js
var frase = 'Amanhã vai chover'; // A frase em causa
var partes = frase.split(' '); //dividir em partes
var posicao_ultima_palavra = partes.length - 1; //encontrar a ultima posicao ultima palavra
var ultima_palavra = partes[posicao_ultima_palavra]; //pegar na ultima palavra(chover neste caso)
partes.pop();//remover a ultima palavra do array
var primeiras_palavras = '';
partes.forEach(function(palavra){//percorrer o array de palavras para formar a frase depois da virgula
primeiras_palavras += ' '; //espaco entre as palavras
primeiras_palavras += palavra; // a palavra em causa
});
var nova_frase = `${ultima_palavra}, ${primeiras_palavras}`; //resultado da contatencacao

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = nova_frase;
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Com o código acima, qualquer palavra que fores a escrever terá o resultado que quiseres.

**UPDATE**

Se quiseres podes usar uma versão mais resumida.

```js
var frase = "Amanhã vai chover"; //A frase em causa
var partes = frase.split(' '); // dividir em partes
var ultima_frase = partes.pop(); // remover a ultima parte com pop e guardar numa variave
var primeiras_palavras = partes.join(' '); // criar uma string separada por espaços(' ') com as partes restantes
var resultado = `${ultima_frase}, ${primeiras_palavras}`; //resultado

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = resultado;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```